# Git filter repo dude with the flags

Tags: git, gitlab, repository

I want to do a general cleanup of my GitLab repository, it currently weighs 2.3 GB and I want to decrease it, I have already removed 700mb in images but when recalculating this size does not decrease. I found these steps with the official GitLab guide where they recommend using git-filter-repo.

git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M

This is the command I run, what would happen if I run

git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1K

Would it remove the files in the repository or just the objects from the git history?

I don't want to lose information, just decrease the weight.

I tried to run this command mainly, but when I upload the commitmap to gitlab, the weight of the repository doesn't change, it's probably because all the files in my repository are too light and nothing is really removed.

git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M

Comment: You could try a new clone to see if the repository size shrinks. It's expected that the size on Gitlab page does not change.  The Gitlab repository preserves all the history data.